# Separating axis theorem falsely triggers

Tags: c++, collision-detection, collision, separating-axis-theorem

I'm writing some code in C++ for testing collisions using the separating axis theorem and in certain orientations it wrongly triggers that there is a collision occurring

I'm following [this](http://www.dyn4j.org/2010/01/sat/) tutorial, however the tutorial is only in 2D and i'm trying to implement it in 3D although i think it should still be the same.

The algorithm that i have now doesn't miss any collisions but for some orientations of the two boxes it thinks that that are colliding when they're infact not. An example can be seen here, these two boxes are apparently colliding according to the code below.

[image: False collision]

The code is written in C++

BoxCollider.h

```
class BoxCollider :
    public Collider
{
public:
    BoxCollider(Vector3 position, Vector3 rotation, Vector3 size);


    ~BoxCollider();

    void Update();

public:
    Vector3 rotation;
    Vector3 size;
    Matrix transformMatrix;

    std::vector<Vector3> points;

    Vector3 normals[3];
};
```

BoxCollider.cpp

```
BoxCollider::BoxCollider(Vector3 position, Vector3 rotation, Vector3 size) : rotation(rotation), size(size)
{
    this->position = position;
    points.resize(8);

}

BoxCollider::~BoxCollider()
{
}

void BoxCollider::Update()
{
    Transform* eTransform = m_entity->GetComponent<Transform>();
    transformMatrix.RotateYawPitchRoll(rotation + eTransform->rotation);
    Vector3 ePos = eTransform->position;

    points[0] = transformMatrix * (Vector3( 0.5, -0.5, -0.5) * size) + position + ePos;
    points[1] = transformMatrix * (Vector3( 0.5,  0.5, -0.5) * size) + position + ePos;
    points[2] = transformMatrix * (Vector3( 0.5, -0.5,  0.5) * size) + position + ePos;
    points[3] = transformMatrix * (Vector3( 0.5,  0.5,  0.5) * size) + position + ePos;
    points[4] = transformMatrix * (Vector3(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5) * size) + position + ePos;
    points[5] = transformMatrix * (Vector3(-0.5,  0.5, -0.5) * size) + position + ePos;
    points[6] = transformMatrix * (Vector3(-0.5, -0.5,  0.5) * size) + position + ePos;
    points[7] = transformMatrix * (Vector3(-0.5,  0.5,  0.5) * size) + position + ePos;

    normals[0] = transformMatrix * Vector3(1, 0, 0);
    normals[1] = transformMatrix * Vector3(0, 1, 0);
    normals[2] = transformMatrix * Vector3(0, 0, 1);
}
```

The algorithm:

```
void EntityManager::CheckCollision(BoxCollider * col0, BoxCollider * col1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) //First cube
    {
        Vector3 axis = col0->normals[i];
        axis = Vector3(axis.z, -axis.x, axis.y);


        Projection proj1 = GetProjection(col0->points, axis);
        Projection proj2 = GetProjection(col1->points, axis);

        float overlap = GetOverlap(proj1, proj2);

        if (overlap > 0.0) //The projections do not overlap
            return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) //First cube
    {
        Vector3 axis = col1->normals[i];
        axis = Vector3(axis.z, -axis.x, axis.y);

        Projection proj1 = GetProjection(col0->points, axis);
        Projection proj2 = GetProjection(col1->points, axis);

        float overlap = GetOverlap(proj1, proj2);

        if (overlap > 0.0) //The projections do not overlap
            return;
    }
}

float GetOverlap(Projection proj1, Projection proj2)
{
    float a = proj2.left - proj1.right;
    float b = proj1.left - proj2.right;

    return a > b ? a : b;
}

Projection GetProjection(std::vector<Vector3> points, Vector3 axis)
{
    float tmp = 0;
    float left = D3D10_FLOAT32_MAX, right = -D3D10_FLOAT32_MAX;

    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++)
    {
        tmp = DotProduct(points[i], axis.Normalize());
        if (tmp < left)
        {
            left = tmp;
        }

        if (tmp > right)
        {
            right = tmp;
        }
    }

    return Projection(left, right, axis);
}
```

Comment: What is your question ? Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? I don't think your question fits here, it is unclear what you are asking for, please check the help center and edit you question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> tutorial is only in 2D and i'm trying to implement it in 3D although i think it should still be the same

Unfortunately, it is not the case. The 3D case a little bit more complex. To check whether two complex shapes are colliding in 3D, you need to check every face normal (you do this), and **directions which are perpendicular to an edge of each object** (you miss these).

So, for boxes (A and B), with edge directions A0, A1, A2, and B0, B1, B2, we have:

- 3 normals of A
- 3 normals of B
- 9 directions: A0 x B0, A0 x B1, A0 x B2, A1 x B0, A1 x B1, A1 x B2, A2 x B0, A2 x B1, A2 x B2

So you just need to add the missing 9 checks.

Further note: you don't need to swizzle the normals. I mean this line is not needed:

```
    axis = Vector3(axis.z, -axis.x, axis.y);
```

In this case, it doesn't do any harm. But for more complex shapes, it actually could make the test incorrect.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. When calculating the MTV do i need to do the min  comparison for those faces as well?

Comment: @TimRoberts: do you mean doing the comparison for the "extra" 9 directions? If that's the case, then the answer is yes.

Comment: Basically like this afterive tested if the projection overlap: if (overlap < smallestOverlap)
  {
   smallestOverlap = overlap;
   smallestAxis = axis;
  }

Comment: @TimRoberts: seems OK to me.

Comment: Would this way be the correct way to evaluate the overlap  float a = proj2.left - proj1.right;
 float b = proj1.left - proj2.right;

 return a > b ? a : b; I dont get the MTV to work it teleports the boxes sideways

Comment: @TimRoberts:  a possible problem could be, that overlap amount is not enough information. You need to know which direction you need to move objects. I mean, there could be two cases (let a=smallestAxis*smallestOverlap): move A to A+a*0.5f, and B to B-a*0.5f, or A to A-a*0.5f, and B to B+a*0.5f. Or another problem could be, if smallestAxis is not normalized (so normalize the result of the cross product - but of course, you may get rid of it afterwards. But first implement the algorithm correctly, then optimize).

Comment: @TimRoberts: nope, it was a long time ago when I implemented SAT. Search the net, there should be some materials on this.